# AD B2C - CopyClaim Doesn't Copy value to 'SignInName'

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm working on an Azure AD B2C custom policy where the policy receives only the email address in Orch step 1. The policy recognizes if the email address already exists and if yes, the user is taken to the sign in page. If account does not exist, user is taken to signup page.

Both the Signin page and signup page need to show the email address that the user entered in previous step as a readonly email. So I use a 'copyClaim' to copy the email address to a readonly email address.

This works fine for signup page. However, it doesn't work as expected in signin page. In Signin page, it is still asking the user to enter the email address.

Please check the related technical profiles:

Sign-in technical profile - I've used the built-in technical profile and included a copyclaim:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
        <InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyOldUserEmailAddress" />
        </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

The TP uses built-in 'login-noninteractive' validation technical profile:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
          <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">query</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">email openid</Item>
            <!-- <Item Key="grant_type">password</Item> -->

            <!-- Policy Engine Clients -->
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="username" Required="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="password" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="openid" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="nca" PartnerClaimType="nca" DefaultValue="1" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="oid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" PartnerClaimType="upn" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Here's the Claims Transformation CopyOldUserEmailAddress:

```
    <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyOldUserEmailAddress" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailAddress" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </ClaimsTransformation>
```

I'm confident that the claimtype 'emailAddress' is passed on to the signin orchestration step correctly as removing the step gives the expected ID token.

I am starting to think this is some sort of security measure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you change the definition of signInName? It's not readonly by default.

What happens if you remove:

```
DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"
```

Comment: Wonderful! It was right in front of my eyes for the past 1 day and I couldn't figure it out. Thank you so much Rbrayb. 

The culprint is 'AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" - It was in the built-in Technical profile. After removing it, it works fine.